# Facebook image doesn't show when I share a page

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-share

Could someone tell me why facebook don't pull the header image from this page http://goo.gl/JiNz3W

This is what I'm getting when I'm sharing something from my page: 
http://prntscr.com/65gc9m

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: does it occur to every image in every page you share on facebook?

Comment: Missing meta
<meta property="og:image" content="image url here">

Comment: @JeanGkol No, if I share homepage ( index page ) of the page on which I reported the problem in that case I'm getting image properly shared on facebook.

Comment: let me know how your current script to share it

Comment: @JeanGkol I don't use script. I just copy/paste URL to facebook.

Comment: what url you got, let me know :D

Comment: @KonohamaruTenshi I added that tag but unfortunately it doesn't help. Please check source code and you will see: 
<meta property="og:image" content="http://new.dynamosports.se/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Dynamo_9_02.png">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine now, you have to update fb cache from this page
[developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/)

Screenshot
[image: f]

Answer (score 0):

Try this URL to share on facebook:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://your-url-here/
```

If it doesn't show the image, it could be said that your image is blocked by robots or htaccess.

Now check your image url below (copy and paste in your browser). you'll find what's wrong by yourself:

Click **[HERE](http://new.dynamosports.se/wp-content/themes/dynamo/images/featured_shadow.png)**

Comment: check robots.txt or htaccess if it blocks your image

Comment: I updated my answer. It seems facebook seize your background image